# How do I return a generic Tuple with SqlDataReader

Tags: generics, tuples, sqldatareader

I have the following code:

```
public static Tuple<string, long, long> ExecuteSqlText(string sql, string dbName)
{
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=" + dbName + "");

    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();

    var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    Tuple<string, long, long> tuple = null;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var item1 = reader.GetString(0);
        var item2 = reader.GetInt64(1);
        var item3 = reader.GetInt64(2);
        tuple = Tuple.Create(item1, item2, item3);
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();

    return tuple;
}
```

I want to make this code generic so that I can pass the Tuple type as a generic argument and return that type. And also fill it according to the types in the generic Tuple parameter.